# removing last elements from vector until condition

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I ran into a problem where i need to delete the last elements of a vector until a certain condition is met (for sake of this example let it be the element is not zero)

I wrote this code, it does the trick -

```
auto next = vec.rbegin();
while (next != vec.rend())
{
    auto current = next++;
    if (*current == 0)
        vec.pop_back();
    else
        break;
}
```

But i would much rather find an stl algorithm that i can use (i can use find_if and then erase, but i'd like to loop **once** through the elements that i remove...)

Also, i'm afraid i may be invoking some UB here, should i be worried?

Comment: Have a look at the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Comment: Your loop as written will remove the last `n` elements where `n` is the number of 0s in the entire vector, not the number of 0s at the end. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: @MarkB, thanks, i forgot the else clause.

Comment: @juanchopanza, this loops the last elements more then once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code can be simplier:

```
while( !vec.empty() && vec.back() == 0 ) 
    vec.pop_back();
```

Using `std::remove` or `std::remove_if` would remove all elements based by criteria, so you should use `std::find_if` as Vlad provided in his answer.

Comment: Are you sure they can't use reverse iterators?

Comment: @NeilKirk good question. Documentation about find_first_of requires ForwardIterator, it is unclear if reverse_iterator satisfies that requirement, which would be strange (based on the name)

Comment: This indeed shortens my code, thanks. i'm still looking for some stl algorithm solution so i'll wait a bit, if nothing shows up i'll approve this answer...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example. It uses the general idiom for erasing vectors

```
v.erase( std::remove( /*...*/ ), v.end() )


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0 };

    v.erase( 
        std::find_if( v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 
        []( int x ) { return x != 0; } ).base(), v.end() );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: how about 1 2 3 4 0 5?

Comment: @Slava Here the zero is not the last element. So this sequence shall not be changed.

Comment: yes I see it, you find first element that is not equal to 0 from the end. Good idea.

Comment: This was my initial implementation but this causes me to iterate the last elements twice (once until the non-zero is found and once to erase the elements)